# Collapsible menu will not stay closed on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile drop down menu that will not stay closed when the window is resized or dragged to a larger or smaller dimension. Is it possible to keep the menu collapsed only until the menu is opened when you click on it?

The menu is collapsed when the page is loaded, however, once you drag the window to resize it, the menu opens on its own.

Thanks for any help!

------->

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('button.open-menu');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
HTML

<!----------------------------MOBILE NAVIGATION MENU----------------------------------->
<div class="mobile-nav-container">
<button class="open-menu"><img src="images/menu-button.svg"></button>
<nav class="nav-menu">
<ul class="nav-menu">
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="current-journal.html">CURRENT JOURNAL</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="subscribe.html">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="submit.html">SUBMIT MATERIAL</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="submission-guidelines.html">SUBMISSION GUIDELINES</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="http://3elementsreview.blogspot.com">3E BLOG</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="past-journals.html">PAST JOURNALS</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="about-3elements.html">ABOUT 3ELEMENTS</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="the-editors.html">THE EDITORS</a></li>
<li class="mb-nav"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div><!----------------------MOBILE NAV CONTAINER  END------------------------------->
CSS

.mobile-nav-container {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#252525;
    top:-5px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #ffd09d;
    z-index:300;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.nav-menu {/*navigation menu as a whole*/
    position:relative;
    top:13px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#252525;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6000;
}

nav ul li a {/*navigation list items*/
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-top:3px;
    line-height:1.9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #313131;
    width:90%;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:myriad pro;
    font-size:1em;
    list-style:none;
    transition:300ms;
    -webkit-transition:300ms;
}

nav ul li {/*drop down list padding settings*/
    list-style:none;
}

nav li a {/*main navigation text color and padding settings*/
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    color:#ffd09d;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav-menu li:active a {/*main navigation TEXT HOVER effects*/
    color:#ff6000;
    background-color:#beb29a;
    transition:400ms;
    -webkit-transition:400ms;
}

.nav-menu li:hover a {/*main navigation TEXT HOVER effects*/
    color:#ff6000;
    transition:300ms;
    -webkit-transition:300ms;
}

button.open-menu {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    left:5%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:40px;
    height:29px;
    display:inline-block;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#353535;
    border:2px solid #424242;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

button.open-menu:active {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px solid #353535;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: you need to rethink why you do `menu.removeAttr('style');`. If element is hidden by `hide()` or `slideUp` or similar, it will have inline style that is hiding it. Would suggest toggling class for the 2 size conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took advice from a comment above, and removed one line of code

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('button.open-menu');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');         <<<-----I REMOVED THIS LINE-----
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```